# Android Studio Kotlin. Unresolved reference getClass()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Trying to compile the following code, but I'm getting unresolved reference errors

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), " OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), not working.");
} else {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), " OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), working.");
}
```

How do I find what I need to import to get this getClass() function to work?

I also have an error `Unresolved reference File` on this line
`val inputFilePath = inputDir + File.separator + inputFileName + "." + inputExtension`

which improt is required to get this to work

Is there a good way to search for what I need to import for future unresolved references?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like a mix of Java and Kotlin. You can't write Java code in a Kotlin file.

There is no `getClass()` in Kotlin. Instead of `.getClass()`, use `::class.java`. Or in this specific case, you don't need `.java`, since a Kotlin KClass also has a `.simpleName` property (not getter function).

To import File, hover over the word File and the IDE will suggest auto-importing it for you. So for the most part, you don't need to memorize packages for imports.